# What triggers the Behemoth train on Sinai Desert?

Tags: battlefield-1

During conquest games on Sinai Desert, a armored train will occasionally spawn for 1 team.

I have only seen it spawn for the opposing team so far, once at the last minute of the game and once around 10 left.
At first i thought you had to control all or a specific map point to trigger it, but that has proven false in my experience.

Answer (score 3):

[Behemoths](http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/Behemoth) spawn *at most once* per map. They are given to the loosing team to *"help turn the tide of the battle"*.

> A Behemoth is a special vehicle meant to give an advantage to a losing
>   team to help them close the ticket gap between them and their enemies.

What exactly triggers them isn't 100% clear, though it's rumored that it's based on time and ticket gap.

> Behemoths may appear during Conquest or Operations matches. A Behemoth
>   will spawn once a certain criteria is met and players will have the
>   option to spawn into it on death. Should the criteria not be met, the
>   vehicle may not spawn. In the alpha build, the behemoth appeared
>   midway into a Conquest match, was automatically destroyed two minutes
>   before the end of the round, and did not respawn for the remainder of
>   the round. In the open beta, the behemoth remains to the end of the
>   round.

Comment: i'll give this a +1 but i'm looking for a more detailed answer.

Comment: @Vahx I have noticed it tends to be at about 150 ticket gap in Conquest and I have to assume there is a minimum and maximum limit time/ticket wise, but i have gotten it at about 100 tickets before which was pretty early into the game. In Operations, the attackers get it at the beginning of every round except the first round.